# Convert Mysql Query into Laravel 4 Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, laravel-5

I want to convert this query into Laravel 4 Eloquent.

```
$query = SELECT * FROM standard_products WHERE frame_category like "%1%" OR
frame_category like "%2%" OR frame_category like "%3%";
```

Here I have an array

```
$frame = Array([1]=1,[2]=2,[3]=3);
```

Requirement:

Using `$frame` array I want to get same result in Laravel Eloquent

My effort is:

```
 foreach ($frame as $val) {
     $match = Standard_product::orWhere('frame_category','like','%'.$val.'%');
 }
     $match =  $match->get()->toArray();
```

But result of `$match` is not equal to `$query`. Please help me to

Comment: Could you format your code snippets to make them readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$frame = Array(1,2,3);
$q = DB::table('standard_products');
foreach ($frame as $val) {
    $q = $q->orWhere('frame_category','like','%'.$val.'%');
}
```

Produces

```
select *
from   `standard_products`
where  `frame_category` like ?
or     `frame_category` like ?
or     `frame_category` like ?
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like as

```
Model::where(function ($query) use ($frame) {
    foreach($frame as $val){
        $query->orWhere('frame_category','like',"%$val%");
    }
})->get();
```